# How do I handle collision sounds with many objects?

Tags: unity, c#, sound, sound-effects

I have a game where I am dropping blocks onto a wooden platform.  The idea of the game is to stack them whilst keeping them balanced.

The blocks fall from a height.  Sometimes they land on the plank, other times on other blocks.  Players will opt to stack them close together.

I want to make a noise when the block hits something, so I have the following code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log("Cube collided");
    Debug.Log(other.collider.GetComponent<Collider>().tag);
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
```

This is attached to my block.

The sound plays, however it feels extremely unrealistic.  The block makes the same noise no matter what the velocity of the impact.  If a block becomes jammed between other blocks then it makes a few sounds, all of the same sound it makes when hitting the plank from a height.

Is there a way of creating more realistic 3D sounds?  I guess I'm after a noise and falloff based off of the velocity, but that might not be the case, I'm a little unsure.  This seems like a very common usecase but I am struggling to find anything online about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AudioClip audioClip;
AudioSource audioSource;

void Start () {
    audioClip = Resources.Load("click") as AudioClip;
    audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    float audioLevel = collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude / 10.0f;
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip, audioLevel);
}
```

The above code is from another project I have worked on, so I know it works. You'll probably have to modify it or your existing code to match your scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Unity provides you with `Collision.relativeVelocity`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html

The basic example inside the documentation already solves one of your problems: **Don't play a sound, when the collision occured with a low velocity by using a threshold**. This prevents small unwanted turbulence inside the physics engine or insignificant vibrations to cause a storm of sounds to be played.

You can also **use the relative velocity to play the sound at different volume levels**. A "soft landing" is going to be quiet and a block falling at high speed will be loud. Don't forget to cap the volume to prevent unpleasant loud sounds. You can take it a step further, by **playing different sounds for different impact strengths**.

**Use multiple impact sounds and pitch variations to create variety**. If the same sound is being repeated often, it can quickly become annoying.

**Use different sounds when two different materials collide**, if your objects are made out of different materials.

Edit:
Another obvious pitfall, you can easily fall into is described in DMGregorys comment below.

Comment: One other trick I've used is to have the collision sound script inspect the object it collided with. If the other object also has the collision sound script, I pick just one of them to play the sound, so I don't get muffled overlapping audio when two of the same object hit each other. ;)